# Ajax data to FLOT chart in correct format?

Tags: c#, ajax, flot

I know there are several posts about this but I think I'm missing something. I'm returning the data below in an ajax call but it doesn't seem to be in the right format for FLOT. Is there a better format to return the data in or what should be changed for FLOT to recognize it? TIA

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function() {
         // Add the page method call as an onclick handler for the div.
         $("#Result").click(function() {
             $.ajax({
                 type: "POST",
                 url: "WebTest.aspx/GetData",
                 data: "{}",
                 contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                 dataType: "json",
                 success: function(msg) {
                     // Replace the div's content with the page method's return.

                     var jsObj = []
                     jsObj.push($.parseJSON(msg.d));

                     $.plot($("#Result"), jsObj, {
                         grid: {
                             backgroundColor: "#E5E5E5",

                             mouseActiveRadius: 20
                         }


                     }
                 );
                 }
             });
         });
     });
</script>


[WebMethod]
public static string GetData()
{

    DataLines dataLine1 = new DataLines();
    DataLines dataLine2 = new DataLines();


    int[] lineA_Point1 = new int[] { 4, 6 };
    int[] lineA_Point2 = new int[] { 2, 10};

    List<int[]> dataA = new List<int[]>();
    dataA.Add(lineA_Point1);
    dataA.Add(lineA_Point2);

    dataLine1.data = dataA;
    dataLine1.label = "DataLine1";

    JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();

    string Line1 = js.Serialize(dataLine1);

    return Line1;
}
```

Comment: In your example is msg.d supposed to be d?  If so, d should be a javascript array, not a string that looks like a javascript array.

Comment: I added the server side code where I'm attempting to create the lines - do I need to make the changes here?

Comment: No, your web method is returning a proper JSON string.  You need to convert that back to a javascript object.  Try: `d = $.parseJSON(d)`

Comment: Actually I take that back.  It's not proper JSON.  I'll answer the question...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1.) Convert the JSON string back to a javascript object in your javascript:

```
var jsObj = $.parseJSON(d); // using jquery method
```

2.) In your GetData method, your

```
dataLine1.data = "[[1356328800000,5],[1356933600000,3]]";
```

isn't going to work.  That will make your data element a string in the JSON instead of a javascript array.  It would be best to fix this in your WebMethod:

```
DataLines dataLine1 = new DataLines();
dataLine1.data = new List<int[]>();
dataLine1.data.Add(new int[] {1356328800000,5});
dataLine1.data.Add(new int[] {1356933600000,3});
```

That's totally untested (I've never used the `JavaScriptSerializer` before, but similar code works with the ServiceStack serializer.

Comment: thanks Mark - a flavor of that worked. The date is the issue now because it is a long not an int.

Comment: nevermind... I just changed it to long[] and that took care of it