# Flot and C# WebMethod

Tags: c#, flot, webmethod

anyone got any good resources for creating a Flot chart, using a c# webmethod. The data will be pulled from a database.

All examples I've come across have hard coded values.

Cheers

ok, i'm calling my WebMethod, and loop through the rows in a datatable, but instead of getting [[1,2],[2,2]] im getting drlist[0] - drlist[49]

Using this loop

```
  List<DataRow> drList = new List<DataRow>();
    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
    {
        drList.Add((DataRow)row);
    }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14364512/ajax-data-to-flot-chart-in-correct-format

Comment: BlackICE, seen this thanks, again these are hard code values

Comment: Not sure I understand, what are the hard-coded values in that link?

Comment: int[] lineA_Point1 = new int[] { 4, 6 };
    int[] lineA_Point2 = new int[] { 2, 10};

Answer (score 2):

There is an [example](http://people.iola.dk/olau/flot/examples/ajax.html) on Flot website which takes JSON data using AJAX call to a server. Basically this seems to be what you need, just insert a URL of your web method returning data in JSON format.

Comment: Thanks Alexander, I was looking for c# examples as well if you have any

Comment: have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14364512/ajax-data-to-flot-chart-in-correct-format

Comment: Hi Blake, correct me if i'm wrong, but as mentioned above, these values appear to be hard coded. i.e, {4,6} & {2,10}. I'm looking to return my values dynamically from a datatable

Comment: It doesn't matter, I hard coded the values in that example for help but the data is dynamic - coming from a DB. All you need to do is replace the values in that data structure with the values from your datatable.