# Flot Ajax Realtime Chart Not get data from CS Page

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, flot

I'm trying an example of a Flot Ajax Realtime chart with the data coming from the cs page but the data is not getting passed. The chart gets created but the data points don't show up.  What am I missing?

Default.aspx

```
<%@ Page Title="Flot Examples: Real-time updates" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/flot/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/flot/jquery.flot.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/flot/jquery.flot.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/flot/jquery.flot.time.js"></script>    
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/flot/jquery.flot.axislabels.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/flot/jshashtable-2.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/flot/jquery.numberformatter-1.2.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/flot/jquery.flot.symbol.js"></script>

<!-- Javascript -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    var cpu = [], cpuCore = [], disk = [];
    var dataset;
    var totalPoints = 100;
    var updateInterval = 5000;
    var now = new Date().getTime();

    var options = {
        series: {
            lines: {
                lineWidth: 1.2
            },
            bars: {
                align: "center",
                fillColor: { colors: [{ opacity: 1 }, { opacity: 1}] },
                barWidth: 500,
                lineWidth: 1
            }
        },
        xaxis: {
            mode: "time",
            tickSize: [60, "second"],
            tickFormatter: function (v, axis) {
                var date = new Date(v);

                if (date.getSeconds() % 20 == 0) {
                    var hours = date.getHours() < 10 ? "0" + date.getHours() : date.getHours();
                    var minutes = date.getMinutes() < 10 ? "0" + date.getMinutes() : date.getMinutes();
                    var seconds = date.getSeconds() < 10 ? "0" + date.getSeconds() : date.getSeconds();

                    return hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds;
                } else {
                    return "";
                }
            },
            axisLabel: "Time",
            axisLabelUseCanvas: true,
            axisLabelFontSizePixels: 12,
            axisLabelFontFamily: 'Verdana, Arial',
            axisLabelPadding: 10
        },
        yaxes: [
            {
                min: 0,
                max: 100,
                tickSize: 5,
                tickFormatter: function (v, axis) {
                    if (v % 10 == 0) {
                        return v + "%";
                    } else {
                        return "";
                    }
                },
                axisLabel: "CPU loading",
                axisLabelUseCanvas: true,
                axisLabelFontSizePixels: 12,
                axisLabelFontFamily: 'Verdana, Arial',
                axisLabelPadding: 6
            }, {
                max: 5120,
                position: "right",
                axisLabel: "Disk",
                axisLabelUseCanvas: true,
                axisLabelFontSizePixels: 12,
                axisLabelFontFamily: 'Verdana, Arial',
                axisLabelPadding: 6
            }
        ],
        legend: {
            noColumns: 0,
            position:"nw"
        },
        grid: {      
            backgroundColor: { colors: ["#ffffff", "#EDF5FF"] }
        }
    };

    function initData() {
        for (var i = 0; i < totalPoints; i++) {
            var temp = [now += updateInterval, 0];

            cpu.push(temp);
            cpuCore.push(temp);
            disk.push(temp);
        }
    }

    function GetData() {
        //set no cache
        $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });

        $.ajax({
            url: 'Default.aspx',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: update,
            error: function () {
                setTimeout(GetData, updateInterval);
            }
        });
    }

    var temp;

    function update(_data) {
        //remove first item of array
        cpu.shift();
        cpuCore.shift();
        disk.shift();

        now += updateInterval


        //add the data retrieve from backend to array
        temp = [now, _data.cpu];
        cpu.push(temp);

        temp = [now, _data.core];
        cpuCore.push(temp);

        temp = [now, _data.disk];
        disk.push(temp);


        //update legend label so users can see the latest value in the legend
        dataset = [
            { label: "CPU:" + _data.cpu + "%", data: cpu, lines: { fill: true, lineWidth: 1.2 }, color: "#00FF00" },
            { label: "Disk:" + _data.disk + "KB", data: disk, color: "#0044FF", bars: { show: true }, yaxis: 2 },
            { label: "CPU Core:" + _data.core + "%", data: cpuCore, lines: { lineWidth: 1.2}, color: "#FF0000" }        
        ];

        //redraw the chart
        $.plot($("#flot-placeholder1"), dataset, options);

        //prepare for the update
        setTimeout(GetData, updateInterval);
    }


    $(document).ready(function () {
        initData();

        dataset = [        
            { label: "CPU", data: cpu, lines:{fill:true, lineWidth:1.2}, color: "#00FF00" },
            { label: "Disk:", data: disk, color: "#0044FF", bars: { show: true }, yaxis: 2 },
            { label: "CPU Core", data: cpuCore, lines: { lineWidth: 1.2}, color: "#FF0000" }
        ];

        $.plot($("#flot-placeholder1"), dataset, options);
        setTimeout(GetData, updateInterval);
    });


    </script>

    <!-- HTML -->
    <div style="width:900px;height:600px;text-align:center;margin:10px">        
        <div id="flot-placeholder1" style="width:100%;height:100%;margin:0 auto"></div>     
    </div>
</asp:Content>
```

Default.asp.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting;

public partial class _Default : Page
{

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Page.Controls.Clear();

        Random rnd = new Random();

        int CPUloading = rnd.Next(0, 100);

        int CPUcore = CPUloading - 30 < 0 ? 0 : rnd.Next(0, CPUloading - 30);

        int Disk = rnd.Next(56, 1024);

        Response.Write("{\"cpu\":" + CPUloading + ", \"core\":" + CPUcore + ", \"disk\":" + Disk + "}");

    }
}
```

Comment: What does `Response.Write("{\"cpu\":" + CPUloading + ", \"core\":" + CPUcore + ", \"disk\":" + Disk + "}");` return?  `console.log( _data)` in the update function and update your question.  With flot if the plot shows but no data points, it usually means data is in the wrong format...

Comment: Thanks for the help. I just realized the Response wasn't getting called but it should have been since it was on page load so then I changed my Default.aspx to use asp tags instead of html. Now the Response.Write is getting called but the only output I see on the page is {"cpu":16, "core":0, "disk":516}  and the graph doesn't show any more.

Comment: Looks like your question is now; how to make a proper AJAX call with ASP.NET webforms?  I can't answer that one.  The only .NET webstack I've used is MVC.

Comment: Have a look at this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14364512/ajax-data-to-flot-chart-in-correct-format). Mark actually is the one who suggested it and it works beautifully. I'd also suggest using JavaScriptSerializer to transform your data.